# Money type: remove currency symbol without type casts

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm using MONEY type for currency data in my Postgres table. When I select data, postgres formats values according to system's `lc_monetary` setting.

I would like to get rid of currency symbol in the query result without using explicit type casts (I'm using Laravel's query builder currently. Type casts will require raw queries).

Is there a way to setup `lc_monetary` config setting so that currency values in query results are formatted exactly like simple floats with 2-digit precision and without thousands separator (so that I would be able to use it as a string/float in my PHP code)?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a numeric/decimal with a set precision: `NUMERIC(PRECISION)` or `NUMERIC(precision, scale)`

Comment: @Wolph Well, I know I can change type. But it's interesting to find a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Well, setting the `LC_MONETARY` to nothing should do the trick. But what's the point of using the `MONEY` type if you're not going to use the currency anyhow? It's just a `NUMERIC` in that case.

Comment: @Wolph Setting this config file setting to nothing makes Postgres inherit this from OS, not removing formatting at all. Setting it to nothing in OS is a too heavy thing to do. BTW, do you mean, that Postgres has MONEY type for output formatting purposes only?

Comment: Well, it's slightly more than output formatting actually. Internally the `MONEY` type is actually just stored as a `bigint` internally and the formatting is just added using the `LC_MONETARY` setting. However, if you have a fixed precision anyhow, there is no need for that hassle and you can just set it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people I have talked to reccommend not using the money type. Typically MONEY types get output as strings by your local implementation becuase of the LC_MONETARY formatting. Most people (myself included) recommend using a NUMERIC for your monetary values.

Also you mentioned placing your money values in a float. Floats on computers have rounding errors naturally and can cause issues with monetary amounts, so be careful.

In Python we use the decimal class when we need to do math on money, I assume that PHP has something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Is select money_column/1::money safe...

According to the doc the result of dividing by money is double precision.... (The currency cancels out).